# Why was base 32 question downvoted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, down-votes, post-ban

Can you tell me what's wrong with [How does Base32 encoding work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064126/how-does-base32-encoding-works-in-java) please?

I want to edit it so that it can be helpful to the community. I don't think that just anonymously downvoting can be of any help to the others.

I think it's a clear, short and answerable question. More importantly, as I said in a comment below, I read the documentation and believe me, it was not an easy thing to find. Then I searched the Wikipedia page for `Base32` and I don't know why, the part of the question where I said I searched the wiki, was removed (you can see I did it, by checking the first comment to the question). How is that poor searching?

I am question banned now.

The only reason I'm asking this question is because I want to be a part of this community and I understand I have to learn something to be part of it. Why did you donwvote me again? I feel like I'm being trolled now.

Comment: We don't know. Voting is anonymous. Note that you are *never* banned for just one question being downvoted.

Comment: But though it was anonymous, the comments you received might be an indicator of why people downvoted. I'm not saying that those users did, but it might be a reason for someone to do so.

Comment: If you are question banned, then previous questions were downvoted too. Did you receive comments on those? Did you heed those comments?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The only other question I was downvoted was one where I posted a working code asking for revision and better way to do something, and they said that codereview.stackexchange.com was the place for posting that kind of question. I didn't even know about other stackexchange sites, but I was explained, and that made be happy and has made the community a less dirty place. But the last question?

Comment: Also, the only reason I'm asking this question is because I want to be a part of this community and I understand I have to learn something to be part of it. Why did you donwvoted me again? I feel like I'm being trolled now.

Comment: @domenicop You have 5 negatively scored questions and 7 closed questions. Not just 2, as you seem to imply. All those count towards a ban.

Comment: @Bart it seems you're right, i was downvoted at far more question then I thought, but I can't see why. My worst question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180346/fastest-for-loop and I think it's that kind of question that many, many programmers ask themselves at a certain point in their career (as was suggested in the question given to me), and it was simply posed and easy to understand. What's wrong with that?

Comment: when you call a method and want to know something about it, how about checking the documentation? The documentation (after one level of indirection) answers your question. Ever heard of RTFM?

Comment: the documentation was the first place I went. The info was not that easy to find, try to search for the .toString() function yourself.

Comment: @domenicop: Are you really saying you couldn't find the documentation for `BigInteger.toString(int radix)`? I don't see how it's hard to find: you go to the `BigInteger` documentation, look for the right overload in the "method summary" section and then follow the link for details. That documentation then links to `Character.forDigit`. Which step did you find difficult?

Comment: I just checked and you don't seem to be blocked from asking questions. I _do_ recommend taking a look at questions where you could make edits that actually improve them (clarity, extra info, things you tried or even where and how you searched) and you should move safely away from being blocked again. You seem to care about your posts, that's awesome, just take your time when asking and think .. *will anyone ask if I searched for X?* - if so, search for it, or let us know how / where you did - that goes a long way.

Comment: And to all - he doesn't seem to be complaining, he honestly wants to know _why_ the post was down-voted, presumably to avoid it in the future. That's exactly _what we want_ - go easy on the guy :)

Comment: Your contributions as "a member of the community" seem to be exclusively asking questions. Votes on questions reflect the perceived value of the questions to everyone, so some of your questions seem to be valued better than others, and that's all there's to it. It's not personal, and don't make to much out of it. The votes are just a tool to put some sense of value on the question; they're not a personal statement about you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I never said the info was not there, I almost instantly replied to the first question saying that it escaped to the first read. But to put it all on the table, the only thing that I would care about that particular overload of that method is what's the argument and how it does affect the execution of the statement `object.toString(int radix);`. And to read that, I've to go to another function documentation and read till the last line. I think we can stop here.

Comment: @KerrekSB I tried to reply to some question for a period of time and I ended up answering just one in a whole 4 days of search :) Now that I'm growing as a programmer, I'll try and look more often for question to reply, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @domenicop: I'm sure that you'll find that the more questions you answer, the more you'll grow to appreciate what makes a question "good" -- seeing it from the other side helps a great deal. Good luck!

Comment: @TimPost thank you for your attitude. I'm editing some previous, bad, questions, and it seems I've already got good feedback. Appreciate your participation, thank you again.

Comment: @domenicop: I didn't claim that you *did* say the info was not there. But you said "The info was not that easy to find" - and that's what I'm struggling to understand. It looks pretty simple to find, to me - what went wrong when you tried?

Comment: its now -4/+3 (-4*2 /+3*5) so you get +ve rep :)

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like the comment and close reason pretty well sum up what's wrong with the question...

My suggestion would be to edit the post/s and add addition information, what research did you do, what did you try, what is it doing now, how does what it is doing now conflict with what you would like it to do, etc.

Martijn Pieters pointed out in the comments "...you are never banned for just one question being downvoted." In your case, I can see 7 closed questions in your user profile, 5 of which have negative scores.

Like I said edit, edit, edit...

See: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)
for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Given the flood of actual crap that arrives on the front page every day, I think it's sad to see people taking time to close this one. Yes, the information is there, but what seems obvious to one person post-hoc is not always so obvious to someone who is approaching the problem from scratch. The answer to the question here is that, indeed, five people decided that the information was too obvious to allow the question to be legitimate.

Comment: Jon Skeet voted to close it :/

Comment: Yes, and I'd do so again. The answer is in the documentation, which (despite claims to the contrary) is really not that hard to find. Look at the first version of the question (which is what was closed) - there's no evidence of any research whatsoever. That's a big red flag in my view: Stack Overflow shouldn't be the very first place you go when you have a problem... it shouldn't *replace* research, it should be an option after research has failed.

Comment: I saw it post-edit.

Comment: In the first post I stated I looked in the wiki for what's a base32 conversion and how it can happen. The fact that SO doesn't report that, is so strange. In your comment, given 2 minutes after the question, you seem to refer to that research though.

Comment: @domenicop: No, I was referring to wikipedia as it was the first place *I* looked. There was no indication that *you* has looked at Wikipedia. There's no evidence that in the first post you did actually state that you'd looked in Wikipedia. I suspect this is more likely to be you misremembering what you'd written than a flaw in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Votes are anonymous. People who downvote posts can explain the reason in the comments if they want to, but it's not a requirement.

Basically, it looks like you didn't do enough research before asking the question. I am in no way a Java expert, but it looks like you could have found out the answer to this question with a little bit of research, as Jon Skeet says in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064126/how-does-base32-encoding-works-in-java#comment28177347_19064126).

It's always a good idea to go through the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) before asking a question. Try to answer all the questions in the checklist (I know it's hard). If the answer to any of these questions is *"no"*, you should take the time to fix up your question before posting.

And, many of your [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2081434/domenicop?tab=questions) were downvoted too, and this could by why you were question-banned. Go back to those questions and improve them, if you can.

See also: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: I starred the  Stack Overflow question checklist, thank you for the useful input.

Comment: @domenicop: Sure. You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question was easy to answer using the official documentation. A bit more effort would be nice.

There has been a nice acronym for this kind of question for decades: [RTFM](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/r/RTFM.html)

---

**I wonder Wonder what `BigInteger.toString(32)` does in java...**

Google for ["biginteger class java"](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=biginteger+class+java)

First hit is the [official documentation for `BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

**Now what was the method again?** -> `toString(int)`, that matches the `toString(int radix)` in the page, where you can read:

> The digit-to-character mapping provided by Character.forDigit is used, and a minus sign is prepended if appropriate.
>
> See also:
>
> ... [`Character.forDigit(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit%28int,%20int%29)

click on that link, to read:

> If the digit is less than 10, then '0' + digit is returned. Otherwise, the value 'a' + digit - 10 is returned.

**Question answered.**